# How to use custom directive on Input fields in Angular 1.x?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-directive

I'm trying to modify the `input` element using a custom AngularJS directive. Basically I want to replace any `<input type="country">` fields with a country drop-down.

But the directive doesn't seem to work with `input` fields. If I change it to any other tag, it works?

Here is the code:

```js
angular.module('plunker', [])
.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
});


angular.module('plunker')
.directive('input', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {ngModel: '=?'},
    link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
      if(attr.type === 'country') {
        elem.html('html code for select');
        alert(elem);
      }
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker" >
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script>document.write("<base href=\"" + document.location + "\" />");</script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  Name: <input type="country" ng-model="name"/> <br/>
</body>
</html>
```

Can someone please explain and **suggest a workaround**?

P.S. I've also tried doing this in the directive, but it doesn't work either!

```
replace: true,
template:'<div>hello</div>'
```

P.S. I know I can use a `ng-country` or some other custom tag but I want to change `input` tag only because I want learn why this is happening or possibly find out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Instead of declaring your directive as an element, why not declare it as an attribute?

Comment: You should give the restriction to class/attribute level and custom directive name as any myInput etc.,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Latest Update:**

Your code is just setting the html on the element, instead of replacing it. You would want to use replaceWith instead like this:

```
var app = angular.module("TestApp",[]);

app.controller("TestController", function($scope){
  $scope.message = "Input Directive Test"
});

app.directive("input", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
      if(attr.type === "country") {
        var select = angular.element("<select><option>USA</option></select>");
        elem.replaceWith(select);        
      }
    }
  }
});
```

And here's the JSBin: https://jsbin.com/juxici/4/edit?html,js,output

**Initial Version of my answer:**

Here's an example that works without any issues when 'replace' and 'template' are used. I'm not checking for type and such, but you could do that in the linker code.

JSBin: https://jsbin.com/juxici/2/edit?html,js,output

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-app="TestApp">
  <div ng-controller="TestController">
    <h2>{{message}}</h2>
    <input type="country" ng-model="name"/>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module("TestApp",[]);

app.controller("TestController", function($scope){
  $scope.message = "Input Directive Test"
});

app.directive("input", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    replace: true,
    template:"<select><option>USA</option></select>"
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks! it does seem to work but there is still one problem.. when I run the `$compile` on element it doesn't seem to work still? Any ideas?

Comment: @supersan why are you using $compile? show some code. Did this answer help you with your original question and you are extending the question? Just trying to understand.

Comment: hi, please see this code: https://jsbin.com/yiyideyomu/edit?html,js,output (i need to compile it because I want to use `ng-options` in select)

Comment: See it now: https://jsbin.com/guqekop/edit?html,js,output. You just need to compile it first and then replace. HTH. Don't forget to upvote/mark as answer if this helped you. Thanks.